# Updating table layout content as I insert more rows

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I have two tables (`pendingTable` and `approvedTable`) that contain rows of pending and approved transactions.
I'm reading the data from Firestore and `onComplete` I display these transactions in the `tableViews`,
for some reason I can't update the tables as I process the rows, for example:
I have 10 transactions, I retrieve them sorted from the Firestore DB,
I call a function that inflates a table row view and inserts the data into it
and after that, I add the returned row to the table.

What happens is only after I process all the 10 transactions and get all the rows, they are displayed to the screen, but I want as I process them, to display the ready rows so the table will be updating as I process the rows.

I tried using threads but it's also not working.
calling `postInvalidate();` or `refreshDrawableState();` also doesn't work.

Here are my functions:

```
branchReference.collection("Actions")
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(DISPLAYED_ACTIONS)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        int i = 0, j = 0;
                        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            Action action = document.toObject(Action.class);
                            if(action.isPending()){
                                pendingTable.addView(actionRow(action, document.getReference(), j++));
                            } else {
                                approvedTable.addView(actionRow(action, document.getReference(), i++));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Error handling
                    }
                }
            });
```

actionRow function is just creating a row and adding data to it then returns it

**If it's not possible, how can I make it looks more smooth and faster?**

Comment: So you want, once you add new data to be added in real-time in your view, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Exactly

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of [getting data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), when you are using a "get()" call, it means that you are getting the data **exactly** once. That's the reason why when you add new data, is not added to your view. If you want to get the data in real-time for every change that takes place, then you should [listen for real-time updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

There is also a library that can help y ou achieve that, which is called [Firebase-UI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). So check the documentation, as it has a really easy implementation.

Comment: I don't want to update the real-time updated data that is updating in the firestore, I want to display the rows, after getting them from the DB, and process them, then display them, but I want to display the ready rows (after they are returned from actionRow function)
what is happening is only after all of the rows are ready, they appear

Comment: This is **not** what you answered earlier, you answered "Exactly". What exactly you cannot process after getting data from Firestore?

Comment: Excuse me.
my problem is that the returned processed rows are not being displayed in the tables only until all the rows are ready (the for loop is finished)

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context?

Comment: Im getting data from firestore (transactions) that I want to display in a table, i have a function that takes transaction object, turns it into a tableRow and returns it,
after that i use addView to add the retruned row.
what is happening is only after all the transactions are sent and returned from the function, they appear in the table layout.
i want to show the rows are they getting ready, when transaction i is done, i want it to immediately be displayed (not to wait for all of the transactions to be ready)

Comment: First of all, there are no transactions involved in your code, but just a simple "get()" call. That behavior has most likely has to do with that "action.isPending()" condition. So I think you should reconsider somehow that logic, right?

Comment: The Action object is a transaction, sorry if that was confusing.
the Action object has a property pending 
didnt quite understand what do you mean, can you please be more specific?

Comment: Why do say that the Action object is a transaction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230598/discussion-between-najib-saad-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Hey Najib! Can I help you with other information?